# Official COVID vaccination documentation from the USA

Tags: usa, covid-19, health, ukraine, vaccinations

I'll be traveling to Ukraine next week. One of the requirements for traveling to Ukraine are

> - negative result of PCR test for COVID-19 (validity 72 hours); or
> - a document confirming the receipt of a full course of vaccination against COVID-19 with vaccines included by WHO in the list of approved for use in emergency situations; or
> - a rapid test for the SARS-CoV-2 antigen (RAT) (validity 72 hours)

I received my vaccine some time ago, but only got a slip of paper from the vaccination facility - no official documentation. Is there an official document that I should be obtaining, or does that slip suffice?

Comment: Your question assumes that the paper given to you by the vaccination facility is only a "slip of paper" and not "an official document." This may not be true. Please attach an image of the slip of paper into your question; you can attach a photo by using the "edit" button and then the "moon and mountains" button that appears above the box for text entry. Be sure to obscure your personal details (name, date of birth, or other identifying information) before uploading the photo.

Comment: If you were vaccinated in the USA you should have received a [CDC COVID-19 Vaccination Record Card](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CDC_COVID-19_Vaccination_Record_Card.jpg).  That's the usual form of "official documentation" here.  Is that not what you got?

Comment: @NateEldredge I suppose I did receive that - it just looked so "unofficial" compared to other government documents and records and other countries' systems that I've seen that I dismissed it. Thanks. If you want to write that as a full answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "official documentation" used in the US is the CDC COVID-19 Vaccination Record Card.
[image]

([Image from user whoisjohngalt via Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CDC_COVID-19_Vaccination_Record_Card.jpg))

As you said in your comment, you do have one of those, even if it may look like just a "slip of paper".

Comment: Though if yours does look like the above and shows only a single dose, make sure it makes it very clear that it was a single-dose vaccine, or you may well not be admitted on the ground of being fully vaccinated.

Comment: @MadHatter: The card in the image is unusual in that it has left off the name of the vaccine given.  Normally it would say "Johnson and Johnson" or something like that, which people would hopefully recognize as a single-dose vaccine.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would have hoped, and I think that was my point.

Comment: Mine says "Janssen."  I'm a bit sorry that it doesn't say "Johnson & Johnson/Janssen,"  So many Johnsons, so many languages!  I wonder how easy it is to determine the maker of the vaccine from the lot number alone.  Could that `M/` at the beginning mean "Moderna"?